# Get a facebook page in iframe

Tags: facebook, html, iframe

Can we include a facebook page in side a iframe in HTML?
like-

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/anniyanarises" />
```

It says, `Refuse to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.`

Please tell me is there any other way to include a facebook page in my web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way, and it´s surely against the Facebook Terms. You can only include specific parts of a page with the Graph API or with some Social Plugins: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/